# Problem with type = 'prob' argument in caret::train package

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I am training a randomforest model to classify a raster image using `caret` based on 3 categorical variables. I am interested to get the class membership probabilities for these three categories. This can be done using `type = 'prob'` but the problem is all I get is a single probability image and that ranges from 0 to 1.

> model_rf <- caret::train(xVar ~ . , method = "rf", data = dt_train, importance = TRUE,
> type="prob")
> predict_p_rf <- raster::predict(object = image.x, model = model_rf, type = 'prob')

My question, 1. is there a way to get class membership probabilities for these three categories in three seperate outputs? 2. what is the probability image representing as it ranges from 0 to 1 while there are three different categories. I am not sure if higher values such as 1 represent higher membership to either of existing classes/categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works smoother with `terra::predict` but with `raster::predict` you can use the `index` argument to specificy which output variable(s) you want.

`predict_p_rf <- predict(image.x, model_rf, type = 'prob', index=1:3)`

See `?raster::predict`

The data represent the predicted probability of belonging to a particular category (0 is lowest probability, 1 is highest).